# grunt-spritesmith configuration is not working correctly on gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs, sprite

In my **gruntfile.js** I've this setup for my plugin for generating sprites.
I've to say that everything is well configured, spritesmith is installed via npm install, the plugin is a dependency in the **package.json**.
but there's something else blocking the execution of my sprite command

```
sprite:{
    dist: {
        src: ['css/theme/images/*.jpg'],
        destImg: 'css/theme/sprite/sprite.jpg',
        destCSS: 'css/theme/sprite/spritejpg.css'
    }
},
```

and this is my result but the verbosed message is not the best to understand what's going wrong.

```
C:\wamp\www\myproject>grunt sprite
Running "sprite:dist" (sprite) task
Fatal error: spawn ENOENT
```

What can it be?

Comment: In my scenario, adding this attribute `engineOpts: { 'imagemagick': true }` was enough to make the compiling work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my scenario, adding this attribute to the sprite configuration everything was solved, I guess the default engine configuration did not fit with the plugin. (of course in my machine ImageMagick is installed.

```
sprite:{
    dist: {
        src: ['css/theme/images/*.jpg'],
        destImg: 'css/theme/sprite/sprite.jpg',
        destCSS: 'css/theme/sprite/spritejpg.css',
        engineOpts: { 'imagemagick': true }
    }
},
```