# gradlew build is been failed,only for grunt default it was getting failed

Tags: gradle, gruntjs

I am trying to do  gradlew build in my local machine:

I am getting an error message:
Running "sprite:all" (sprite) task
Fatal error: Unsupported file type: .jpg
                                                                                                :build FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\DL\build.gradle' line: 52
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':grunt_default'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 21.972 secs

using code in Gruntfile.js:

```
sprite:{
        all: {
            src: baseDir + 'web/sass/sprites/*',
            destImg: baseDir + 'web/webroot/_ui/desktop/theme/images/sprites.png',
            destCSS: baseDir + 'web/sass/sprites.scss',
            'cssVarMap': function (sprite) {
                sprite.name = 'sprite-' + sprite.name;
            },
            'padding': 2,
            'algorithm': 'alt-diagonal',
            'imgPath': '../images/sprites.png',

        }

    },
```

Tried to setup imagemagick still it wasn't working

Comment: Try to separate tasks for pngs and jpgs. If that does not work try with `engineOpts: { 'imagemagick': true }` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047162/grunt-spritesmith-configuration-is-not-working-correctly-on-gruntfile-js)

Comment: I think imagemagick is wrong configured to my setup.